# How to create a four dimentional matrix in mathematics?

Tags: matrix

I want to know how to create a four dimensional matrix with index in Mathematica. For example,

`T_{i,j,k,l} = 1` if `i=j=k=l`

`T_{i,j,k,l} = 1/2` otherwise

Then I need to rescale T.

```
hatT_{i,j,k,l} = 1 if i=j=k=l, 
hatT_{i,j,k,l} = (1/sqrt(m))*T_{i,j,k,l} if {i,j} = {k,l}
hatT_{i,j,k,l} = (1/2 * m^2)*T_{i,j,k,l} if {i,j} != {k,l}
```

Comment: There are many ways to create a four-dimensional array.  Example: `Array[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}]` creates a 2x2x2x2 array.  See also `Table[]`.

Comment: Or possibly `Outer[]`.

Comment: But if I want to rescale T which is a four-dimensional matrix, how to access specific entry of that matrix?

Comment: See [Getting Pieces of Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingPiecesOfLists.html) in the documentation.

Comment: See `Part[]`: `T[[i,j,k,l]]`

Comment: To create the initial with 1 on the diagonal, and 1/2 otherwise, should i create a matrix with all entries 1/2 and then replace the diagonal with 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 2;
t = ConstantArray[1/2, {n, n, n, n}]
```

[image]

```
Table[t[[i, i, i, i]] = 1, {i, 1, n}];
t
```

[image]

```
hat = t;

Table[If[{i, j} == {k, l}, 
 hat[[i, j, k, l]] = (1/Sqrt[m]) t[[i, j, k, l]], 
 hat[[i, j, k, l]] = (1/2 m^2) t[[i, j, k, l]]],
  {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]
```

[image]

```
Table[hat[[i, i, i, i]] = 1, {i, 1, n}];

hat
```

[image]

Access parts of `hat`, e.g.

```
hat[[1,2,1,1]]
```

> m^2/4

Comment: If the matrix is " m times m times m times m " (this m is the same as the one used to rescale T), how to write the code? (My final goal is to get a function of m, which is a variable)

Comment: Is setting at the beginning `m=n` what you mean? (In order not to change all the `n`'s in the following codes to `m`'s.)